# Type org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo not present

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to perform "mvn clean package" in my java project and facing the following error :

```
Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:repackage failed: Unable to load the mojo 'repackage' in the plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/springframework/boot/maven/RepackageMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
```

My maven version is :

```
Apache Maven 3.8.7 (b89d5959fcde851dcb1c8946a785a163f14e1e29)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.17, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-56-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Following pom.xml file mojo package :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>javaclass.java</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I still faced the error when my maven version was : Apache Maven 3.6.3
Although the problem got resolved when I upgraded my maven java version to 17 but I want to compile the java code with java version 11.
Does anyone know the fix?

Comment: If you use Spring Boot 3.X you have to use JDK17 and compile to Java 17... You can not compile to Java 11 or using JDK 11... https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.system-requirements